# TSQL Compare comma separated values in a column with a comma separated parameter

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, compare, contains, exists

In my query I have a field `Keywords` which contains a list of values delimited with a semicolon `;`

In my SSRS report one of my parameters `@Keywords` contains a list of all possible individual values in that `Keywords` field.

> How can I pass the multivalued parameter `@Keywords` to my query and check if the field `Keywords` contains any of the selected parameter values?

I have a split function which can delimit `@Keywords` and `Keywords` into their individual keyword items, but how can I perform this check within my Where statement?

`Keywords` example
     `corporate finance; compensation; financial markets`

`@Keywords` example `Accounting,Accounting and Financial Reporting,Agriculture,airlines,corporate finance,compensation,Offshore drilling,Pharmaceuticals,portfolio,anagement`

In those examples, `@Keywords` contains both `corporate finance` and `compensation` so my report would display the record associated with the example `Keywords` field.

As long as @Keywords contains ANY of the values in `Keywords` we want that record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: ResultSet]you may have to expand this to your table selection i just have a proof of concept to to get it working, Cross apply will help you to break the values without any looping or cursors or sub queries.

```
declare @test as table
(
keywords varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @test
VALUES ('corporate finance, compensation, financial markets')

declare @keywords varchar(100) ='Accounting,Accounting and Financial Reporting,Agriculture,airlines,corporate finance,compensation,Offshore drilling,Pharmaceuticals,portfolio,anagement'


select i.RecordID as keywords
from @test a
cross apply dbo.ReturnTableOfVarchars(a.keywords) i
INNER JOIN (select * from dbo.ReturnTableOfVarchars (@keywords)) k
ON k.RecordID=i.RecordID
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced your ReturnTableofVarchars with my own Split function and the results are the two values which are common between the two lists, a huge help. How can I now evaluate that within my `WHERE`? Should I put this into a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1?`

Comment: yes having coutn() or where exists (select .. from the above), @gruff mark it as solved or answer if this resolves your problem